# Autoconf - No POSIX thread support. Configure possibly using wrong code to verify support. How to fix it?

Tags: linux, pthreads, configure, autoconf

I am using ./configure to configure one of the projects. I get the following error from it.

```
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work with -mthreads... no
checking for the pthreads library -lpthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with --thread-safe... no
checking whether pthreads work with -mt... no
checking for pthread-config... no
configure: error: POSIX threads support is required
```

When I check the configure file, I see that it is using the following code to check for pthread support:

```
#include <pthread.h>
int main ()
{
pthread_t th; pthread_join(th, 0);
                     pthread_attr_init(0); pthread_cleanup_push(0, 0);
                     pthread_create(0,0,0,0); pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
  ;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it seperately, it does compile. But with warnings from pthread_create.

```
test_pthread.c:5:22: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]
                      pthread_attr_init(0); pthread_cleanup_push(0, 0);
                      ^
test_pthread.c:6:22: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]
                      pthread_create(0,0,0,0); pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
                      ^
test_pthread.c:6:22: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 3) [-Wnonnull]
```

Is this a bug in the way configure is checking for -pthread support with the compiler? How can I fix this?

I am using autoreconf -i before I run ./configure. What is a clean way to fix this issue?

------------ EDIT: Adding More Info ----------

I am using the following Lines in the configure.ac file to check for pthread. I just got it from a config online.

```
# Check for POSIX thread support

    ACX_PTHREAD([
                     LIBS="$LIBS $PTHREAD_LIBS"
                     CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $PTHREAD_CFLAGS -g -Wall"
                     CC="$PTHREAD_CC"
                     AC_SUBST([LIBS])
                     AC_SUBST([CFLAGS])
                     AC_SUBST([CC])
                 ],
                 [AC_MSG_ERROR([POSIX threads support is required])])
```

Comment: The warnings shouldn't stop the test from succeeding.  You'll need to include in the question more of the autoconf source file that implements those tests.

Comment: @caf: Adding the lines of code I use in the configure.ac file.

Comment: You haven't set `-Werror` in your CFLAGS prior to this point have you?

Comment: Well yes I have. Is it possible to ignore the warnings only for the -pthread library. Something I can add to the configure.ac file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments it is apparent that you have set `-Werror` in your `CFLAGS` early in your autoconf script.

Don't do that.  If you want `-Werror`, add it to `CFLAGS` right at the *end* of the script, after all tests that invoke the compiler have been run.  Most autoconf tests are not written to work with `-Werror`.